# Display HashMap content in tree view

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hashmap, treeview

I need your help because I don't find the solution in Java for my problem.

I stored in object `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` this content:

```
TAG1.TAG2.TAG11 : value1
TAG1.TAG2.TAG12 : value2
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG131 : value3
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG132 : value4
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG133 : value5
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG134 : value6
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG21 : value7
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG22 : value8
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG23 : value9
TAG6 : value10
```

I need to display if a tag has 2 or more children, the list of child.
Here is the expected result:

```
TAG1.TAG2
    TAG11 : value1
    TAG12 : value2
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3
    TAG131 : value3
    TAG132 : value4
    TAG133 : value5
    TAG134 : value6
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5
    TAG21 : value7
    TAG22 : value8
    TAG23 : value9
TAG6 : value10
```

---

**EDIT 14/06/2022 :**

In fact, my original analyse is bad because initialy I have a XML file :

```
<TAG1>
 <TAG2>
  <TAG11>value1</TAG11>
  <TAG12>value2</TAG12>
  <TAG3>
   <TAG131>value3</TAG131>
   <TAG132>value4</TAG132>
   <TAG133>value5</TAG133>
   <TAG134>value6</TAG134>
  </TAG3>
 </TAG2>
 <TAG4>
  <TAG5>
   <TAG21>value7</TAG21>
   <TAG22>value8</TAG22>
   <TAG23>value9</TAG23>
  </TAG5>
 </TAG4>
</TAG1>
<TAG6>value10</TAG6>
```

And I created a map to store it :

```
TAG1.TAG2.TAG11 : value1
TAG1.TAG2.TAG12 : value2
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG131 : value3
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG132 : value4
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG133 : value5
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3.TAG134 : value6
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG21 : value7
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG22 : value8
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5.TAG23 : value9
TAG6 : value10
```

But, today I have a this case :

```
<TAG1>
 <TAG2>
  <TAG11>value1</TAG11>
  <TAG12>value2</TAG12>
  <TAG3>
   <TAG131>value3</TAG131>
   <TAG132>value4</TAG132>
   <TAG133>value5</TAG133>
   <TAG134>value6</TAG134>
  </TAG3>
  <TAG3>
   <TAG131>value11</TAG131>
   <TAG132>value12</TAG132>
   <TAG133>value13</TAG133>
   <TAG134>value14</TAG134>
  </TAG3>
 </TAG2>
 <TAG4>
  <TAG5>
   <TAG21>value7</TAG21>
   <TAG22>value8</TAG22>
   <TAG23>value9</TAG23>
  </TAG5>
 </TAG4>
</TAG1>
<TAG6>value10</TAG6>
```

But the Map object does not allow to store many keys (in the example many TAG3). Have you got an idea how I can resolve this problem ?

---

**EDIT 15/06/2022 :**

In fact the expected result needs to keep the original XML structure.
Here the result of last sample :

```
TAG1.TAG2
    TAG11 : value1
    TAG12 : value2
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3
    TAG131 : value3
    TAG132 : value4
    TAG133 : value5
    TAG134 : value6
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3
    TAG131 : value11
    TAG132 : value12
    TAG133 : value13
    TAG134 : value14
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5
    TAG21 : value7
    TAG22 : value8
    TAG23 : value9
TAG6 : value10
```

It's to display xml more human reader.

---

**EDIT 04/07/2022 :**

I detect a problem of inconsistent with "new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getAppearanceOrder)". Indeed, some MyTag object are the same AppearanceOrder, so there is a problem of inconsistent ordering. Some value in Map are so removed.
To resolve I used :

```
map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(. . .))
```

And I store the result in Map with collect().

Below the working code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        //Accessing the xml file
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new File("data.xml"));

        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

        //Retrieving a List of records where each record contains: the original chain of tags, the numbered chain of tags and the value
        String tagSep = ".";
        List<Record> listRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        visitXMLFile(listRecords, root.getChildNodes(), tagSep, "", "", new HashMap<>());

        //Queue sorted by the numbered tag's length in descending order (from the longest to the shortest)
        PriorityQueue<Record> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(Record::getTagNumberedLen).reversed());
        queue.addAll(listRecords);

        //Using a set to have unique numbered tags (no duplicates) to group by in the resulting map
        Set<MyTag> setMyTags = new HashSet<>();

        //Checking for each numbered tag if its largest substring is equal to any other numbered tag's beginning:
        //  - if it does, then the substring is collected as a key to group by within the final map
        //
        //  - if it doesn't, then another substring is generated from the previous substring until a matching value is found.
        //          If no value is found, then the numbered tag is collected entirely as a key for the resulting map.
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Record rec = queue.poll();

            //This loop keeps creating substrings of the current numbered tag until:
            //  - the substring matches another numbered tag's beginning
            //  - or no more substrings can be generated
            int lastIndexTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            int lastIndexTag = rec.getTag().lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            while (lastIndexTagNum > 0) {

                //Checking if the substring matches the beginning of any numbered tag except the current one
                String subStrTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().substring(0, lastIndexTagNum);
                if (listRecords.stream().anyMatch(r -> !r.getTagNumbered().equals(rec.getTagNumbered()) && r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(subStrTagNum + tagSep))) {

                    String subStrTag = rec.getTag().substring(0, lastIndexTag);
                    int appearanceOrder = listRecords.stream().filter(r -> r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(subStrTagNum + tagSep)).map(r -> r.getAppearanceOrder()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0);

                    //If a match is found then the current substring is added to the set and the substring iteration is interrupted
                    setMyTags.add(new MyTag(subStrTag, subStrTagNum + tagSep, appearanceOrder));
                    break;
                }

                //Creating a new substring from the previous substring if no match has been found
                lastIndexTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().substring(0, lastIndexTagNum).lastIndexOf(tagSep);
                lastIndexTag = rec.getTag().substring(0, lastIndexTag).lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            }

            //If no substrings of the current numbered tag matches the beginning of any other numbered tag,
            //then the current numbered tag is collected as a key for the resulting map
            if (lastIndexTagNum < 0) {
                int appearanceOrder = listRecords.stream().filter(r -> r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(rec.getTagNumbered())).map(r -> r.getAppearanceOrder()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0);
                setMyTags.add(new MyTag(rec.getTag(), rec.getTagNumbered(), appearanceOrder));
            }
        }

        //Creating a temporary resulting map (not sorted as the input)
        Map<MyTag, List<String>> mapTemp = listRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                rec -> {
                                    //Looking for the longest numbered tag which matches the beginning of the current record's numbered tag.
                                    //The reason why we need the longest match (i.e. the most accurate) is because some elements
                                    //may share the same parents but be on different levels, for example the values 3, 4, 5 and 6
                                    //have a key whose beginning matches both "TAG1.TAG2" and "TAG1.TAG2.TAG3", but only the longest
                                    //match is actually the right one.
                                    return setMyTags.stream().filter(mt -> rec.getTagNumbered().startsWith(mt.getTagNumbered())).max(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getTagNumberedLen)).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No key found"));
                                },
                                rec -> {
                                    //Retrieving, like above, the numbered tag that will be used to map the current value
                                    MyTag myTag = setMyTags.stream().filter(mt -> rec.getTagNumbered().startsWith(mt.getTagNumbered())).max(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getTagNumberedLen)).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No key found"));

                                    //If the new numbered tag and the record's numbered tag are equal then a List with the current value is returned
                                    if (myTag.getTagNumbered().equals(rec.getTagNumbered())) {
                                        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(rec.getValue()));
                                    } else {    //If the new numbered tag is a substring of the record's numbered tag then the rest of the current (non-numbered) tag is added to the value
                                        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(rec.getTag().substring(myTag.getTag().length() + 1) + " : " + rec.getValue()));
                                    }
                                },
                                //Handling colliding cases by merging the lists together
                                (list1, list2) -> {
                                    list1.addAll(list2);
                                    return list1;
                                }
                        )
                );

        //Creating a TreeMap whose ordering is based on the insertion order of the input
        Map<MyTag, List<String>> mapRes =
                mapTemp.entrySet().stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getAppearanceOrder)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

        //Printing the resulting map
        for (Map.Entry<MyTag, List<String>> entry : mapRes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void visitXMLFile(List<Record> listInput, NodeList nodeList, String tagSep, String tag, String tagNumbered, Map<String, Integer> mapTagOccurrence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                String newTag = tag.isEmpty() ? node.getNodeName() : tag + tagSep + node.getNodeName();

                //Setting or incrementing the number of appearances of a tag chain
                //(sometimes a same chain of tags can be repeated, ex: TAG1.TAG2.TAG3)
                if (!mapTagOccurrence.containsKey(newTag)) {
                    mapTagOccurrence.put(newTag, 1);
                } else {
                    mapTagOccurrence.computeIfPresent(newTag, (key, val) -> val + 1);
                }

                //Creating a numbered version of the tag where its number of appearances is added at the end.
                //This is done to uniquely identify different groups of tag chain when these are repeated (ex: TAG1.TAG2.TAG3)
                String newTagNum = tagNumbered.isEmpty() ? node.getNodeName() + mapTagOccurrence.get(newTag) : tagNumbered + tagSep + node.getNodeName() + mapTagOccurrence.get(newTag);

                visitXMLFile(listInput, node.getChildNodes(), tagSep, newTag, newTagNum, mapTagOccurrence);
            } else {
                if (!node.getTextContent().trim().equals("")) {
                    int appearanceOrder = listInput.size() + 1;
                    listInput.add(new Record(tag, tagNumbered, node.getTextContent().trim(), appearanceOrder));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTag {

    //Tag chain for the user
    private String tag;

    //Unique tag chain for identification
    private String tagNumbered;

    private int appearanceOrder;

    public MyTag(String tag, String tagNumbered, int appearanceOrder) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.tagNumbered = tagNumbered;
        this.appearanceOrder = appearanceOrder;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public String getTagNumbered() {
        return tagNumbered;
    }

    public int getTagNumberedLen() {
        return tagNumbered == null ? 0 : tagNumbered.length();
    }

    public int getAppearanceOrder() {
        return appearanceOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyTag tagPair = (MyTag) o;
        return Objects.equals(tagNumbered, tagPair.tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tag;
    }
}

class Record {

    //Tag chain for the user
    private String tag;

    //Unique tag chain for identification
    private String tagNumbered;

    private String value;

    private int appearanceOrder;

    public Record(String tag, String tagNumbered, String value, int appearanceOrder) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.tagNumbered = tagNumbered;
        this.value = value;
        this.appearanceOrder = appearanceOrder;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public String getTagNumbered() {
        return tagNumbered;
    }

    public int getTagNumberedLen() {
        return tagNumbered == null ? 0 : tagNumbered.length();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getAppearanceOrder() {
        return appearanceOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Record record = (Record) o;
        return Objects.equals(tagNumbered, record.tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tag + " - " + tagNumbered + " - " + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your initial attempt?

Comment: I don't find a correct algo to initiate something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Edit

At this point to answer your edited question, I had to use a `List` instead of a `Map` to store the input since multiple values share the same key and a `Map<String, List<String>>` wouldn't maintain the insertion order.  In fact, the values from 3 to 6 would be alternated with the values from 11 to 14.

Besides, since the same chain of tags can appear several times (ex: TAG1.TAG2.TAG3), I had to implement two custom classes: `MyTag` and `Record`.

The first class represents a custom tag made of two fields: `tag` and `tagNumbered`. The first field holds the tag chain that must be shown to the user, while the second is used as the actual identifier to group by in the stream operation. `tagNumbered` is basically a copy of `tag` where at the end of each nested tag is added its number of appearances.

Instead, the class `Record` is used to represent a value accompanied by its tag chain and numbered tag chain.

So, the following XML is represented as follows by the respective classes:

```
<x>
    <y>
        <z>value1</z>
    </y>
    <y>
        <z>value2</z>
    </y>
</x>
```

**Record**:

```
Record1:
    - tag: x.y.z
    - tagNumbered: x1.y1.z1
    - value: value1

Record2:
    - tag: x.y.z
    - tagNumbered: x1.y2.z1  //because y appears twice within x
    - value: value2
```

**MyTag** (`MyTag` is created from `Record`):

```
MyTag1:
    - tag: x.y.z
    - tagNumbered: x1.y1.z1

MyTag2:
    - tag: x.y.z
    - tagNumbered: x1.y2.z1  //because y appears twice within x
```

Here is an XML sample based on your question's input, that I've used for the code below.

```
<root>
    <TAG1>
        <TAG2>
            <TAG11>value1</TAG11>
            <TAG12>value2</TAG12>
            <TAG3>
                <TAG131>value3</TAG131>
                <TAG132>value4</TAG132>
                <TAG133>value5</TAG133>
                <TAG134>value6</TAG134>
            </TAG3>
            <TAG3>
                <TAG131>value11</TAG131>
                <TAG132>value12</TAG132>
                <TAG133>value13</TAG133>
                <TAG134>value14</TAG134>
            </TAG3>
        </TAG2>
        <TAG4>
            <TAG5>
                <TAG21>value7</TAG21>
                <TAG22>value8</TAG22>
                <TAG23>value9</TAG23>
            </TAG5>
        </TAG4>
    </TAG1>
    <TAG6>value10</TAG6>
</root>
```

---

##### Original Answer Updated

The first part of the problem consists in creating a `List<Record>` while reading from the XML file which is achieved with the `visitXMLFile` method.

After reading the records from the file, we need to create a `Set` of unique numbered tag chains to identify each group of values. This is actually done with a `Set<MyTag>`; however `MyTag`'s `equals()` and `hashCode()` are based exclusively on `tagNumbered`.

After creating the `Set` of unique numbered tags, we need to stream the input list of entries with a single operation: `collect(Collectors.toMap())`. In this operation, each record is mapped to a `MyTag` (i.e., a numbered tag) of the `Set` previously created.

Finally, to maintain the original insertion order, the resulting `Map` has been implemented as a `TreeMap` initialized with a `Comparator` defined on the order of the input list's records.

Here is an implementation with detailed comments explaining the whole logic step by step:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        //Accessing the xml file
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document document = builder.parse(new File("data.xml"));

        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

        //Retrieving a List of records where each record contains: the original chain of tags, the numbered chain of tags and the value
        String tagSep = ".";
        List<Record> listRecords = new ArrayList<>();
        visitXMLFile(listRecords, root.getChildNodes(), tagSep, "", "", new HashMap<>());

        //Queue sorted by the numbered tag's length in descending order (from the longest to the shortest)
        PriorityQueue<Record> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(Record::getTagNumberedLen).reversed());
        queue.addAll(listRecords);

        //Using a set to have unique numbered tags (no duplicates) to group by in the resulting map
        Set<MyTag> setMyTags = new HashSet<>();

        //Checking for each numbered tag if its largest substring is equal to any other numbered tag's beginning:
        //  - if it does, then the substring is collected as a key to group by within the final map
        //
        //  - if it doesn't, then another substring is generated from the previous substring until a matching value is found.
        //          If no value is found, then the numbered tag is collected entirely as a key for the resulting map.
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Record rec = queue.poll();

            //This loop keeps creating substrings of the current numbered tag until:
            //  - the substring matches another numbered tag's beginning
            //  - or no more substrings can be generated
            int lastIndexTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            int lastIndexTag = rec.getTag().lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            while (lastIndexTagNum > 0) {

                //Checking if the substring matches the beginning of any numbered tag except the current one
                String subStrTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().substring(0, lastIndexTagNum);
                if (listRecords.stream().anyMatch(r -> !r.getTagNumbered().equals(rec.getTagNumbered()) && r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(subStrTagNum + tagSep))) {

                    String subStrTag = rec.getTag().substring(0, lastIndexTag);
                    int appearanceOrder = listRecords.stream().filter(r -> r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(subStrTagNum + tagSep)).map(r -> r.getAppearanceOrder()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0);

                    //If a match is found then the current substring is added to the set and the substring iteration is interrupted
                    setMyTags.add(new MyTag(subStrTag, subStrTagNum + tagSep, appearanceOrder));
                    break;
                }

                //Creating a new substring from the previous substring if no match has been found
                lastIndexTagNum = rec.getTagNumbered().substring(0, lastIndexTagNum).lastIndexOf(tagSep);
                lastIndexTag = rec.getTag().substring(0, lastIndexTag).lastIndexOf(tagSep);
            }

            //If no substrings of the current numbered tag matches the beginning of any other numbered tag,
            //then the current numbered tag is collected as a key for the resulting map
            if (lastIndexTagNum < 0) {
                int appearanceOrder = listRecords.stream().filter(r -> r.getTagNumbered().startsWith(rec.getTagNumbered())).map(r -> r.getAppearanceOrder()).min(Comparator.naturalOrder()).orElse(0);
                setMyTags.add(new MyTag(rec.getTag(), rec.getTagNumbered(), appearanceOrder));
            }
        }

        //Creating a temporary resulting map (not sorted as the input)
        Map<MyTag, List<String>> mapTemp = listRecords.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                rec -> {
                                    //Looking for the longest numbered tag which matches the beginning of the current record's numbered tag.
                                    //The reason why we need the longest match (i.e. the most accurate) is because some elements
                                    //may share the same parents but be on different levels, for example the values 3, 4, 5 and 6
                                    //have a key whose beginning matches both "TAG1.TAG2" and "TAG1.TAG2.TAG3", but only the longest
                                    //match is actually the right one.
                                    return setMyTags.stream().filter(mt -> rec.getTagNumbered().startsWith(mt.getTagNumbered())).max(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getTagNumberedLen)).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No key found"));
                                },
                                rec -> {
                                    //Retrieving, like above, the numbered tag that will be used to map the current value
                                    MyTag myTag = setMyTags.stream().filter(mt -> rec.getTagNumbered().startsWith(mt.getTagNumbered())).max(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getTagNumberedLen)).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("No key found"));

                                    //If the new numbered tag and the record's numbered tag are equal then a List with the current value is returned
                                    if (myTag.getTagNumbered().equals(rec.getTagNumbered())) {
                                        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(rec.getValue()));
                                    } else {    //If the new numbered tag is a substring of the record's numbered tag then the rest of the current (non-numbered) tag is added to the value
                                        return new ArrayList<>(List.of(rec.getTag().substring(myTag.getTag().length() + 1) + " : " + rec.getValue()));
                                    }
                                },
                                //Handling colliding cases by merging the lists together
                                (list1, list2) -> {
                                    list1.addAll(list2);
                                    return list1;
                                }
                        )
                );

        //Creating a TreeMap whose ordering is based on the insertion order of the input
        Map<MyTag, List<String>> mapRes = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getAppearanceOrder));
        mapRes.putAll(mapTemp);

        //Printing the resulting map
        for (Map.Entry<MyTag, List<String>> entry : mapRes.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void visitXMLFile(List<Record> listInput, NodeList nodeList, String tagSep, String tag, String tagNumbered, Map<String, Integer> mapTagOccurrence) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                String newTag = tag.isEmpty() ? node.getNodeName() : tag + tagSep + node.getNodeName();

                //Setting or incrementing the number of appearances of a tag chain
                //(sometimes a same chain of tags can be repeated, ex: TAG1.TAG2.TAG3)
                if (!mapTagOccurrence.containsKey(newTag)) {
                    mapTagOccurrence.put(newTag, 1);
                } else {
                    mapTagOccurrence.computeIfPresent(newTag, (key, val) -> val + 1);
                }

                //Creating a numbered version of the tag where its number of appearances is added at the end.
                //This is done to uniquely identify different groups of tag chain when these are repeated (ex: TAG1.TAG2.TAG3)
                String newTagNum = tagNumbered.isEmpty() ? node.getNodeName() + mapTagOccurrence.get(newTag) : tagNumbered + tagSep + node.getNodeName() + mapTagOccurrence.get(newTag);

                visitXMLFile(listInput, node.getChildNodes(), tagSep, newTag, newTagNum, mapTagOccurrence);
            } else {
                if (!node.getTextContent().trim().equals("")) {
                    int appearanceOrder = listInput.size() + 1;
                    listInput.add(new Record(tag, tagNumbered, node.getTextContent().trim(), appearanceOrder));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyTag {

    //Tag chain for the user
    private String tag;

    //Unique tag chain for identification
    private String tagNumbered;

    private int appearanceOrder;

    public MyTag(String tag, String tagNumbered, int appearanceOrder) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.tagNumbered = tagNumbered;
        this.appearanceOrder = appearanceOrder;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public String getTagNumbered() {
        return tagNumbered;
    }

    public int getTagNumberedLen() {
        return tagNumbered == null ? 0 : tagNumbered.length();
    }

    public int getAppearanceOrder() {
        return appearanceOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        MyTag tagPair = (MyTag) o;
        return Objects.equals(tagNumbered, tagPair.tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tag;
    }
}

class Record {

    //Tag chain for the user
    private String tag;

    //Unique tag chain for identification
    private String tagNumbered;

    private String value;

    private int appearanceOrder;

    public Record(String tag, String tagNumbered, String value, int appearanceOrder) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.tagNumbered = tagNumbered;
        this.value = value;
        this.appearanceOrder = appearanceOrder;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public String getTagNumbered() {
        return tagNumbered;
    }

    public int getTagNumberedLen() {
        return tagNumbered == null ? 0 : tagNumbered.length();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getAppearanceOrder() {
        return appearanceOrder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Record record = (Record) o;
        return Objects.equals(tagNumbered, record.tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(tagNumbered);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return tag + " - " + tagNumbered + " - " + value;
    }
}
```

##### Output

```
TAG1.TAG2
    TAG11 : value1
    TAG12 : value2
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3
    TAG131 : value3
    TAG132 : value4
    TAG133 : value5
    TAG134 : value6
TAG1.TAG2.TAG3
    TAG131 : value11
    TAG132 : value12
    TAG133 : value13
    TAG134 : value14
TAG1.TAG4.TAG5
    TAG21 : value7
    TAG22 : value8
    TAG23 : value9
TAG6
    value10
```

Comment: Interessing, it's work. But it seems the result is not ordering as xml source. How can keep this order ?

Comment: @ZeeCos I've updated the code and the testing link.  I simply added a TreeMap with a Comparator based on the order of the given LinkedHashMap's entries.

Comment: Thanks to you, the result is good :) I upgrade the difficulty, because I forget a case in my request... I edited my post.

Comment: @ZeeCos I've updated the answer with a few explanations of what I've changed. You can find the new code and also a new link to test the code.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to keep xml structure. I edit the post with sample.

Comment: @ZeeCos at this point, part of the problem lies also in how you read the XML file, because you need to keep track of when a tag closes and the same one re-opens within the same level. What XML library are you using?

Comment: I use DOM library

Comment: @ZeeCos updated the answer. However, since in the code there is also the part reading from the XML file, I couldn't emulate that on jdoodle and post a link to test the code. You need to test it locally on your machine.

Comment: I read each line of your code, it's better than lesson in class. It's very interessing and I discover some functions ans logics. Really thank you. I could try to test that tomorrow.

Comment: I try to execute a test with a new input xml file. But the last tag does not work. Here  my input sample : https://ctxt.io/2/AADgrqgZEQ

Comment: It seems the problem is in the Collectors to fill the mapTemp variable.

Comment: @ZeeCos it actually works for me.... https://ctxt.io/2/AADgfs7wFA

Comment: check the SBloc3 SBloc4 and SBloc5. It is not separate, all these values are in SBloc3

Comment: @ZeeCos you're right let me look into it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245668/discussion-between-zeecos-and-dan).

Comment: @ZeeCos it was a small typo. Within the loop that populates `Set<MyTag>`, I forgot to keep track of the `lastIndex` of the non-numbered tag. So, the grouping by was actually happening correctly but the value shown at video was halted one level higher; hence making it look to group by the wrong values. This was the single instruction missing that caused the bug: `lastIndexTag = rec.getTag().substring(0, lastIndexTag).lastIndexOf(tagSep);`

Comment: All my unit tests have passed. The algorithm is perfect! I will try to redo it in SAX, to compare if I do better in performance. I'll keep you in touch.

Comment: On my tests, I have found a problem with "new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingInt(MyTag::getAppearanceOrder)". Indeed, some MyTag object are the same AppearanceOrder, so there is a problem of inconsistent ordering.
Some value in Map are so removed. I try to search another solution to do the sort